# Using named_scope with counts of child models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2, named-scope

I have a simple parent object having many children.  I'm trying to figure out how to use a named scope for bringing back just parents with specific numbers of children.

Is this possible?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bars
    named_scope :with_no_bars, ... # count of bars == 0
    named_scope :with_one_bar, ... # count of bars == 1
    named_scope :with_more_than_one_bar, ... # count of bars > 1
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :foo
end
```

I'm hoping to do something like `Foo.with_one_bar`

I could write methods on the parent class for something like this, but I'd rather have the power of the named scope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars

  # I don't like having the number be part of the name, but you asked for it.
  named_scope :with_one_bar, :joins => :bars, :group => "bars.foo_id", :having => "count(bars.foo_id) = 1"

  # More generically...
  named_scope :with_n_bars, lambda {|n| {:joins => :bars, :group => "bars.foo_id", :having => ["count(bars.foo_id) = ?", n]}}
  named_scope :with_gt_n_bars, lambda {|n| {:joins => :bars, :group => "bars.foo_id", :having => ["count(bars.foo_id) > ?", n]}}

end
```

Called like so:

```
Foo.with_n_bars(2)
```

Comment: In general I agree with the name thing, I would normally make it a generalization and pass a parameter, like in your lower examples, but in the detailed case the name is important.  

There's only a problem around using count. Foo.with_one_bar.count will inflate the answer.   .size works fine, and I can futz and the rest to work.

Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for "with_no_bars" ?

Comment: for a scope `with_no_bars`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#comment36635507_18082147

Answer (score 6):

I would use the [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) for this. Therefore you need the following migration:

```
class AddBarCount < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up  
    add_column :foos, :bars_count, :integer, :default => 0  

    Foo.reset_column_information  
    Foo.all.each do |p|  
      p.update_attribute :bars_count, p.bars.length  
    end  
  end  

  def self.down  
    remove_column :foos, :bars_count  
  end
end
```

Than you need too change you `Bar` model like this:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Now the count of `bars` is cached in the `foo` model, that will speed up your queries for the count of `bars`.

Your named_scopes then have too look like this:

```
#rails 2
named_scope :with_no_bars, :conditions => { :bars_count => 0 }
named_scope :with_one_bar, :conditions => { :bars_count => 1 }
named_scope :with_more_than_one_bar, :conditions => ["bars_count > 1"]

#rails 3 & ruby 1.9+
scope :with_no_bars, where(bars_count: 0)
scope :with_one_bar, where(bars_count: 1)
scope :with_more_than_on_bar, where("bars_count > 1")

#rails 4* & ruby 1.9+
scope :with_no_bars, -> { where(bars_count: 0) }
scope :with_one_bar, -> { where(bars_count: 1) }
scope :with_more_than_one_bar, -> { where("bars_count > 1") }
```

That way you can save time counting `bars` for each `foo` every time you make such a request.

I got this idea watching the railscast about counter cache: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

* [What's new in Active Record [Rails 4 Countdown to 2013]](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013)

Comment: Thanks Jens, pretty cool solution, I'll check out that Railscast as well.