# Find by Quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have a model

```
Vehicle
```

and it

```
has_many :wheels
```

What is the correct find / :conditions => ... statement to find only vehicles with 3 or more wheels, e.g. tricycles, cars, trucks, tanks etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the same, but I believe you can solve your Problem with the help of the answers to this question: [Using named_scope with counts of child models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900031/using-named-scope-with-counts-of-child-models)

In Short:

Add `wheels_count` column to your vehicle table

```
class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle, :counter_cache => true # this will autoupdate the wheels_count on Vehicle
end
```

Now you can search your Vehicle by the count of Wheels:

```
# for all Vehicles with 4 Wheels
Vehicle.all(:condition => { :wheels_count => 4 })
# or for all Vehicles with more than 3 Wheels
Vehicle.all(:condition => ["wheels_count > ?", 3])
```

**Update:**

```
class AddWheelCount < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up  
    add_column :vehicles, :wheels_count, :integer, :default => 0  

    Vehicle.reset_column_information  
    Vehicle.all.each do |p|  
      p.update_attribute :wheels_count, p.wheels.length  
    end  
  end  

  def self.down  
    remove_column :vehicles, :wheels_count  
  end
end
```

So the wheels_count is set to the current count

Comment: ah i see. this looks good. i hope adding the :counter_cache this late in (millions of records) will still work.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the migration, so it should work with millions of already existing records.