# Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I found one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900187/385532) that had some usable `having` examples for finding parents with `n` children, but the same is not usable for finding parents with no children (presumably since the join excludes them).

```
scope :with_children, joins(:children).group("child_join_table.parent_id").having("count(child_join_table.parent_id) > 0")
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

## Update Rails 6.1

With the new Rails version this becomes simple, as described [here](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/01/21/rails-6-1-adds-query-method-missing-to-find-orphan-records.html):

```
.where.missing(:children)
```

For older versions see below.

## Rails 3 & 4

```
scope :without_children, includes(:children).where(:children => { :id => nil })
```

The big difference here is the `joins` becoming a `includes`: an include loads all the relations, if they exists, the join will load only the associated objects and ignore the object without a relation.

In fact, `scope :with_children, joins(:children)` should be just enough to return the Parent with at least 1 child. Try it out!

---

## Rails 5

> See @Anson's answer below

---

## Gem [`activerecord_where_assoc`](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc)

The [`activerecord_where_assoc`](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc) gem can do this for Rails 4.1 up to 6.0.

```
scope :without_children, where_assoc_not_exists(:children)
```

Self-referencing relation are handled seemlessly.

This also avoids issues such as `joins` making the query return multiple rows for a single record.

---

As @MauroDias pointed out, **if it is a self-referential relationship** between your parent and children, this code above won't work.

With a little bit of research, I found out how to do it:

Consider this model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
```

How to return all items with no child(ren):

```
Item.includes(:children).where(children_items: { id: nil })
```

How did I find that `children_items` table?

`Item.joins(:children)` generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT "items".* 
FROM "items" 
 INNER JOIN "items" "children_items" 
 ON "children_items"."parent_id" = "items"."id"
```

So I guessed that Rails uses a table when in need of a JOIN in a self-referential case.

---

**Similar questions:**

- [How to query a model based on attribute of another model which belongs to the first model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633301/how-to-query-a-model-based-on-attribute-of-another-model-which-belongs-to-the-fi/23633352#23633352)
- [Rails active record querying association with 'exists'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234602/rails-active-record-querying-association-with-exists/18234998#18234998)
- [Rails 3, has_one / has_many with lambda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515225/rails-3-has-one-has-many-with-lambda-condition/13516285#13516285)
- [Join multiple tables with active records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266069/join-multiple-tables-with-active-records/24266583#24266583)

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, same for the `with_children` scope - thanks @MrYoshiji!

Comment: What if children were the same class from the parent, a self join, how would this work? Example: 
class Item has_many :variations, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => 'parent_id'

Comment: @MrYoshiji WOw...pretty! Thank You guy!
 works even if the table calls 'items'

Comment: Love your trick with `scope :with_children, joins(:children)`, solved my problem (not the one OP had)!

Comment: I used to do in another way, but correct me if I am wrong:
```scope :without_affiliations, -> { includes(:affiliations).where({id: nil}) }```
when,  ``` \has_many :affiliations, :inverse_of => :professor, :dependent => :delete_all```
where  ```has_many :universities, :through => :affiliations ```

Answer (score 32):

@MrYoshiji has a solid Rails 4 answer, but for folks coming here with Rails 5 you have more options.

**Using Rails 5:**

As of Rails 5, you can also use [left_outer_joins](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins) to avoid loading the association. It was introduced in pull request [#12071](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12071).

```
scope :without_children, -> { left_outer_joins(:children).where(children: { id: nil }) }
```

For parents with children, MrYoshiji's Rails 4 solution is still the one to use:

```
scope :with_children, -> { joins(:children).uniq }
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method `left_outer_joins' for #<Domain:0x0000559c59008840>
from /box/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'`

Comment: @Tom, it looks like your Domain model is ActiveModel, not ActiveRecord, so it wouldn't have any of the [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html)

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved it for Rails 5:

```
scope :without_comments, -> do
  left_outer_joins(:comments).where(comments: { id: nil })
end
```