# ActiveRecord query for all categories that DO NOT have children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a basic Schema:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id', dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: 'Category'
end
```

I want to get all Category objects that DO NOT have any subcategories.

How can I use ActiveRecord to get this result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children Similar question?

Comment: @Pierre: Using the query in the linked question results in: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "subcategories"`

Comment: Post your code in the question.

Comment: The following Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18082147/976775 was updated to match the self-referential cases. In your case, it would be something like `includes(:subcategories).where(subcategories_categories: { id: nil })`

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
Category.where('not exists(select * 
     from subcategories sc 
     where sc.id=categories.subcategory_id)')
```

Obviously you can make it a scope for readability.