# show all companies that have a job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have an association between jobs and companies where company `has_many: jobs` and job `belongs_to: company`. Now I am trying to access a page where there are only companies that have a job, so for this i have this code in my controller

```
def recruiting
  @companies = Company.all
end
```

and this is my recruiting page

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %> 
  <% unless company.job.nil? %>
   <%= link_to company.name, company_path(company), title: "#{company.name}" %>
<% end %> 
<% end %>
```

This doesn't work and gives me an error `undefined method job'`

Comment: This is not the best way to do it. It loops through all Company records and skip only the ones that does not have a job. You could do it directly in your SQL to save execution time. (see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to *only* return companies with jobs and not have to worry about if/unless logic in the views, you can do:

```
def index 
  @companies = Company.joins(:jobs).uniq
end
```

But if you want to return companies both with and without jobs, you should be including jobs so that you aren't making a SQL call on each iteration of the loop.

```
@companies = Company.includes(:jobs)
```

Comment: this is a better answer that the one accepted, you shouldn't be filtering in records in your view layer

Answer (score 2):

Please, replace `<% unless company.job.nil? %>` with `<% if company.jobs.any? %>`

Comment: I have replaced with unless company.jobs.empty? and it is working

Comment: that was another option :P Just if you like "unless" more than "if" :P

Comment: This is not the best way to do it. It loops through all Company records and skip only the ones that does not have a job. You could do it directly in your SQL to save execution time

Answer (score 0):

When you have a has_one relation, the form is singular (job). In has_many, there are multiple jobs, so the form is plural.

So

```
company.jobs.nil?
```