# finding childrenless models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope, model-associations

I have a self-association in a model

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Person"
has_many :children, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: "Person"
```

getting the parents with `where(parent_id: nil)`

How do I get all person models with no children as a scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
scope :with_no_children, -> { includes(:children).where(children: { id: nil }) } # or children_items: { id: nil } if that's self-referencing association
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children)