# Rails many to many return records with no association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model-associations

I have a many to many relationship between `Domains` and `Families`

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :domains_families
  has_many :domains, through: :domains_families
end

class DomainsFamily < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family
  belongs_to :domain
end

class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :domains_families
  has_many :families, through: :domains_families
end
```

I would like to get all `families` that do not have any `domains`

I created this method, it works but I know it can be done more efficiently

```
def self.no_domains
  families = []

 all.each do |family|
   families << family if family.domains.blank?
 end

 families
end
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: `Family.includes(:domains_families).where(domains_families: {domain_id: nil})` will this work. actually im not sure about `postgresql`

Comment: Oops I didn't know marking as Duplicate would actually close your question, I thought it was going to open a vote to mark it as Duplicate. I hope I didn't ruin your post ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of : [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)

```
scope :without_children, includes(:children).where(:children => { :id => nil })
```

---

In your case:

```
Family.includes(:domains).where(domains: { id: nil })
```

Comment: Thanks sorry about the duplicate