# getting .count of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, associations

I have a **Ticket.rb** model, and **School.rb** model.

Ticket `belongs_to` School

School `has_many` Tickets

How can I use ActiveRecord to find out total `.count` of how many Tickets each School has?

I'm aware that `Ticket.where(:school_id => -insert School ID here-).count` will give me the individual count of each school but I'm using this to populate the data into a graph so I really need something more like `School.tickets.count`.

Is this possible without messing up my associations?

Thanks all..

Comment: I think you should use a named scope. It's the cleanest. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2900031/1251349

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ticket.group(:school_id).count
```

This will give you the count of tickets for each school id with key as the school_id and the value as the ticket count

If you want to group by a different attribute on School, then

```
Ticket.joins(:school).group("schools.name").count
```

Eg output:

```
{3 => 10, 4 => 30}
```

Comment: Thank you. What if my School model had a 'name' column that I'd rather have show instead of the ID? i.e. {School 1 => 10, School 2 => 30}

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific School instance (such as `@school`), you can use
`@school.tickets.count`.

For better performance, you can use the `group` method in your controller outlined [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group).

So in your controller:

```
def someaction
  @school_tickets = Ticket.group(:school_id)
end
```

and in your view you can loop through the `@school_tickets` such as:

```
@school_tickets.each do |school_ticket|
  school_ticket.count
end
```

Comment: There is no `group_by` method on ActiveRecord class. Did you mean `Ticket.all.group_by`? Because `group_by` is available only for arrays